# I want to upgrade Magento from 2.3.3 to 2.4.6 p3. What are the important steps we should take

Tags: upgrade

I want to upgrade Magento 2.3.3 to 2.4.6 p3. Please elaborate the steps.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must complete the upgrade prerequisites to prepare your environment before starting the upgrade process.

Steps Need to Taken in consecutive manner :

- Switch to maintenance mode to prevent access to your store during the upgrade process. `bin/magento maintenance:enable`
- To prevent data corruption, disable all cron jobs.`bin/magento cron:remove`
- Start all message queue consumers manually to ensure that all messages are consumed. `bin/magento cron:run --group=consumers`
- Create a backup of the composer.json file. `cp composer.json composer.json.bak`
- You’ll need to prepare the system requirements before starting the upgrade process :

  - Composer: 2.2.
  - Elasticsearch (you can use Elasticsearch or OpenSearch, just use one of them): 8.4 or 7.17 for Magento version 2.4.6
  - MySQL (you can use MariaDB or MySQL, just use one of them): 8.0 for Magento version 2.4.6
  - PHP 8.1 or 8.2 for Magento version 2.4.6
  - For more information on the system requirements for upgrading Magento and Adobe Commerce, please refer to the official documentation https://experienceleague.adobe.com/docs/commerce-operations/installation-guide/system-requirements.html
- Install or update the Composer root update plugin. `composer require magento/composer-root-update-plugin ~2.0 --no-update && composer update`
- Upgrade your instance using the following composer require-commerce command syntax:`composer require-commerce magento/<product> <version> --no-update`
- Update the dependencies. `composer update`

After Above All commands run successfully, Run the below Commands :

```
php -d memory_limit=-1 bin/magento s:up
php -d memory_limit=-1 bin/magento s:d:c
php -d memory_limit=-1 bin/magento s:s:d -f
```

After Verify your work.

Above all steps are necessary to perform a successful upgrade. Rest I have shared the reference links which is helpful to me in upgrading the magento instance.

[Reference Link 1](https://magetu.com/how-to-upgrade-to-magento-version-2-4-6-or-2-4-5-or-2-4-4)

[Reference Link 2](https://experienceleague.adobe.com/docs/commerce-operations/upgrade-guide/implementation/perform-upgrade.html?lang=en)